# double integral getting different results

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I am trying to calculate the double integral $$\lim_{b \to 0^+} \int_{b}^1 \int_b^1 \frac{y-x}{(y+x)^3}dydx$$ If you plug this into wolfram, you get $-\frac{1}{2}$ and if you plug it into symbolab you get $\frac{1}{2}$ I will show you my steps, I just want to make sure I got the right answer.

$$\lim_{b \to 0^+} \int_{b}^1 \int_b^1 \frac{y-x}{(y+x)^3}dydx=\lim_{b \to 0^+} \int_{b}^1 \int_b^1 \frac{y+x}{(y+x)^3}-\frac{2x}{(y+x)^3}dydx$$
$$=\lim_{b \to 0^+} \int_{b}^1 \frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}dx=\lim_{b \to 0^+} \frac{1}{1+x}\Big|_b^1=\frac{-1}{2}$$ I just wanted to verify because these two different websites are giving me different answers.

Comment: I believe symbolab is incorrect here.

Comment: When I do the integration in $y$ I get $$\int_b^1\frac{b}{(b+x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\,dx$$ left to integrate. And it integrates to zero. This seems natural, since the original function is antisymmetric in the line $y=x$.

Comment: @mickep How do you get that, when I do the integration in $y$, I get a $\frac{1}{x+b}-\frac{x}{(b+x)^2}$ that turns to 0, what am I doing wrong? Can I not put the limit into the integral and make that term 0?

Comment: Your mistake seems to be in the step where you integrate $y$ and insert limits. Since you do not show all steps there, it is difficult to see what is going wrong. A primitive in $y$ is $-y/(x+y)^2$. Insert $y=1$ and $y=b$ and subtract, and you will see that you do not get $-1/(1+x)^2$ as a result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are incorrect.  The integral is zero.

To understand why, you can see that the integrand is antisymmetric in $x$ and $y$; specifically, if $$f(x,y) = \frac{y-x}{(x+y)^3},$$ then $$f(y,x) = -f(x,y).$$  So on a square region $[b, 1]^2$, the integral is always zero.  Taking the limit as $b \to 0^+$ does not change this fact.

Here is how the integral should be evaluated in *Mathematica*:

`Integrate[(y - x)/(y + x)^3, {x, b, 1}, {y, b, 1},  Assumptions -> 0 < b < 1]`

The answer given is `0`.  If you instead entered

`Integrate[(y - x)/(y + x)^3, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`

You will get `-1/2`, which is incorrect, but I should stress here that it is wrong not because *Mathematica* made a computational error, but because this expression is not the same as what you are actually trying to evaluate!  That is to say, $$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^1 \frac{y-x}{(x+y)^3} \, dy \, dx \ne \lim_{b \to 0^+} \int_{x=b}^1 \int_{y=b}^1 \frac{y-x}{(x+y)^3} \, dy \, dx.$$  To give you an sense of why this is the case, try evaluating $$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{y-x}{(x+y)^3} \, dx \, dy.$$  If you do this in *Mathematica*, the result is `1/2`.  The integrand does not satisfy Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Can you tell me which step I went wrong? I understand your logic, but I thought all my algebra was fine. Is it because in the integration on $y$ I got rid of a term instead of keeping it around?

Comment: @Panphobia Your algebra is okay but you have made an incorrect assumption that the interval of integration for $y$ is from $0$ to $1$ regardless of the value of $b$; that is to say, you cannot switch the order in which you perform the integration with the act of taking the limit of $b$.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I think the correct result is $0$.
Where I think you got it wrong is in the second equality, where you exchange limit and the integral for one term.

Here I sketched some more detailed computations:
\begin{align}
  \lim_{b \to 0}
    \int_b^1 \int_b^1 \frac{y-x}{(y+x)^3}dydx
{}={} &
  \lim_{b \to 0}
     \int_b^1 \int_b^1
        \left(\frac{y+x}{(y+x)^3}-\frac{2x}{(y+x)^3}\right)dydx
\\
{}={} &
  \lim_{b \to 0}
     \int_b^1 
        \left(
          -\frac{1}{y+x}\Bigg|_{y=b}^{y=1}
          +
          \frac{2x}{2(y+x)^2}\Bigg|_{y=b}^{y=1}
         \right)dx
\\
{}={} &
  \lim_{b \to 0}
     \int_b^1 
        \left(
          \frac{1}{b+x}
          -\frac{1}{1+x}
          +
          \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}
          -\frac{x}{(b+x)^2}
         \right)dx
\\
{}={} &
  \lim_{b \to 0}
     \int_b^1 
        \left(
          \frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}
          +\frac{b}{(b+x)^2}
         \right)dx
\\
{}={} &
  \lim_{b\to0}
  \left(
    \frac{1}{1+x}
    -\frac{b}{b+x}
    \Bigg|_{x=b}^{x=1}
  \right)
\\
{}={} &
  \lim_{b\to0}
  \left(
    \frac{1}{2}
    -\frac{1}{1+b}
    +\frac{b}{2b}
    -\frac{b}{b+1}
  \right)
\\
{}={} &
   0
\end{align}